# Where should the " if __name__ = '__main__' " idiom be placed when using the Python multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am running Windows 7.

In my main module, I call a function, `A`, which is in module `a`.

```
import a

a.A(listOfInputTuplesForB)
```

`A` calls multiple instances of the function `B`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def A(listOfInputTuplesForB):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count())
        pool.map(poolWrapperForB, listOfInputTuplesForB)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

def poolWrapperForB(inputTuple):
    return B(*inputTuple)

def B(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print "I did nothing with my arguments!"
```

Now, obviously, when I run my main module, nothing happens, as the conditional `if __name__ == '__main__'` fails, since `__name__ == 'a'`.

Where should `if __name__ == '__main__'` go in this program?

Comment: What does this have to do with multiprocessing?

Comment: @juanchopanza the python `multiprocessing` module

Comment: So are you saying this problem wouldn't happen if you didn't use multiprocessing?

Comment: @juanchopanza well, it was an issue with me using the module correctly, hence "usage" issue, which was in my original title -- I have updated my title in order to better reflect the question.

Comment: My question was rhetorical. This has nothing to do with multiprocessing or the multiprocessing module.

Comment: @juanchopanza Rhetorical questions (usually) do not serve much purpose on a Q&A site, apart from stroking inflated egos, as you just showed. In any case, in my limited knowledge, I felt it had something to do with the correct usage of the `multiprocessing` module, and I still do not understand why this has nothing to do with the `multiprocessing` module. More importantly, I wonder why you are simply not suggesting how I can edit the question in order to improve it, so that I can implement said suggestion.

Comment: Usually that kind of question triggers some kind of thought process that makes the recipient realise that they may be barking up the wrong tree. The thought process itself helps the learning process. That is the purpose of such a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove main from `def A(listOfInputTuplesForB):` and put it in the other file.

```
import a

if __name__ == "__main__":
  a.A(listOfInputTuplesForB)
```